# character map object max value occurrence

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a character map and i'm trying to setup a function that looks for multiple occurrence of the highest value and return it in an array [{H:2}, {E:2}, R:{2}];
if there was say another character in charMap X and it's value was 3 then the array would only be [{X:3}]

```
const charMap = {H: 2, I: 1, T: 1, E: 2, R: 2};
```

I can do this to get the highest number and return the character but it will always return the last highest char.

```
const reduced = Object.keys(charMap).reduce((a, b) => {
  return charMap[a] > charMap[b] ? a : b; 
});
```

I'm thinking maybe a double for loop to check one against the other but not sure if that is overkill. 
Any ideas how to do this.

Comment: Please define what's the expected output in the examples you provided

Comment: You can do this in a single iteration or in two - imho two (one for finding the max, then collecting all letters of that value) is easier to read and preferrable here. `let max = Math.max(...Object.values(charMap)); let result = Object.entries(charMap).reduce((p, [character, value]) => value === max ? (p.push({ [character]: value }), p) : p, []);`

Comment: @ASDFGerte Can you please explain this as I have no idea whats going on here. Could this be done with a for loop as I feel it might be more clear than with reduce.

Comment: just add a filter and you get the result

Comment: Tbh i have the tendancy to cram some example code into comments when there is no answer yet, while it may not be the best idea. Comments make it hard to format code or add enough to make it properly readable. Take it as example, not as answer (otherwise i'd post it as such). Sure, this can be done with a variety of different approaches.

Comment: @me-me you have a solution and you want a better one right ?

Comment: Thanks ASDFGerte I understand. I'm going to work through your solution thanks.

Comment: Stakvino no i'm sure ASDFGerte solution is great, I'm just more used to the old school for i=0 loops so wanted to see if there was a way of doing it that way. I'm sure I can work this out from the reduce solution ASDFGerte posted. This is all for learning purposes anyway.

Comment: It likely works, but in hindsight, i think writing a solution that has to fit in half a comment and can have no formatting, for a problem where readability is the biggest concern, might not have been the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to consider is that there are 26 characters, maybe 52 when thinking case sensitive, and perhaps a couple dozen more when allowing for some other symbols. Any considered solution is O(n). Together, this means when writing the code, there are no concerns about performance, and therefore readability should be the priority (It does not matter, whether we iterate all characters once or ten times).

We need the following:

- The maximum value of any property of `charMap`
- all properties (characters) that have said maximum as value
- all said properties formatted as `{ [character]: maximum }` in an array

```js
const charMap = { H: 2, I: 1, T: 1, E: 2, R: 2 };

// Get the maximum value
let max = Math.max(...Object.values(charMap));

// For the example `charMap`, this will be 2
console.log(`Maximum: ${max}`);

// Get all properties that have the value of the maximum.
// Here we need access to both key and value.
// One could loop over the keys and get the values
// by using charMap[key], but i prefer having both ready.
let charsWithMaxValue = Object.entries(charMap).filter(
  ([key, value]) => value === max
);

// the result of this, for the example, looks like this:
// [["H", 2], ["E", 2], ["R", 2]]
// Don't worry about the JSON, it's just to make
// it easily readable in the console
console.log(`charsWithMaxValue: ${JSON.stringify(charsWithMaxValue)}`);

// Alternative (note that this changes the format
// of the intermediate result, so formatting code
// also needs to change if this is used):
/*
let charsWithMaxValue = Object.keys(charMap).filter(
  key => charMap[key] === max
);
// alternate intermediary result:
// ["H", "E", "R"]
*/

//Format to the desired result
let result = charsWithMaxValue.map(
  ([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value })
);

// Alternative formatting:
/*
let result = charsWithMaxValue.map(
  key => ({ [key]: max })
);
*/

console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
```

Note this uses a few more modern features, e.g. `Object.values` or `Object.entries`.

The code in my comment does the filtering and formatting steps as one, partly because of issues when cramming code into a comment, producing imho less readable code than just doing three steps where each one is hopefully more clear.

Comment: Amazing thanks for the detailed explanation, this is great to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate through `charMap` with `for..in` and aggragate highest as below

```js
let charMap = {  H: 2,  I: 1,  T: 1,  E: 2,  R: 2 };
let highest, result = [];

for (var key in charMap) {
  if (!result.length || charMap[key] > highest) {
    result = [{
      [key]: charMap[key]
    }]
    highest = charMap[key]
  } else if (charMap[key] === highest) {
    result.push({
      [key]: charMap[key]
    })
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks JagsSparrow for this solution. I marked ASDFGerte as the answer because he was first to answer and made detailed comments for me to learn from. I really appreciate you showing this solution. I hate having to mark one or the other when all this is amazing learning. Thank you!